# iOS: add system sound to button in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

is there a way using system sound  like Apple calculator app

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

help appreciated

believe have some different I mean using system sound
the question posted is focus on using url sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **AudioToolbox** framework. Example usage (making the device vibrate):

```
import AudioToolbox.AudioServices

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

Full documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox

To try out another constants, see this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/system_sound_services/1618202-alert_sound_identifiers

or just command+click on the constant `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` to see other constants.

Comment: thanks....could you give me another example not vibrate but play a system sound... I'm confused with SystemSoundID

Comment: See my edit. Basically, the `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate` is just a constant.

Comment: but only kSystemSoundID_Vibrate working for iPhone ..